# Better way to use plyr (or other) to create a variable using seq from 2 other variables

Tags: r, plyr

I've got some data that contains admission and discharge dates, and I need to (for each person and admit ID #), create a wide-to-long-ish dataframe that contains person and admit ID with the sequence between admit and discharge indicating a value for every day in between and including admit and discharge.

I've stumbled on a very hack-ish way of doing this that takes advantage of how dlply names the items in the list it creates; however, I worry that it *might* be error prone.  Either way, it feels clumsy, and I wonder if there is a cleaner way of doing this using less code.

```
person <- c(1, 2, 3, 3)
admit <- c(1, 1, 1, 2)
admit.date <- as.Date(c("1/1/2010", "1/1/2010", "1/1/2010", "2/1/2010"), "%m/%d/%Y")
discharge.date <- as.Date(c("1/1/2010",  "1/1/2010", "1/1/2010", "2/1/2010"), "%m/%d/%Y") + c(1,2,2,2)
df1 <- data.frame(person, admit, admit.date, discharge.date)
df1 ## where I start

library(plyr)
los_seq <-  function(df) { seq(df$admit.date, df$discharge.date, 1)} 
lst1 <- dlply(df1, .(person, admit), los_seq)
vec1 <- unlist(lst1)
## now it gets really hackish
df2 <- data.frame(v1 = paste(names(vec1), vec1, sep="__"))
df2$person <- substr(df2$v1, 1, regexpr("\\.", df2$v1)-1)
df2$admit <- substr(df2$v1, regexpr("\\.", df2$v1)+1,  regexpr("\\.", df2$v1)+1)
df2$date <- as.Date(as.numeric(substr(df2$v1, regexpr("__", df2$v1)+2,  nchar(df2$v1))), origin="1970-01-01")
df2[,-1]  ##  this is how I need the result to look
```

Comment: Please make your example reproducible. I assume that `lst1` should be `df2`. And, I can't see what you are looking for in `df2$date`.

Comment: Yes.  I actually noticed the error after re-reading my post and changed it almost immediately (a few minutes after the original posting).  Not fast enough for you to not only come up with a more elegant solution, but also infer my intent despite the unedited post.  very nice indeed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using something like the following (since you're using actual dates):

```
SEQ <- df1$discharge.date - df1$admit.date + 1
df1[rep(row.names(df1), SEQ), 1:2]
#     person admit
# 1        1     1
# 1.1      1     1
# 2        2     1
# 2.1      2     1
# 2.2      2     1
# 3        3     1
# 3.1      3     1
# 3.2      3     1
# 4        3     2
# 4.1      3     2
# 4.2      3     2
```

---

And now, to guess as to what you might be referring to in your comment, perhaps you're also looking for the sequence of dates.

```
SEQ <- df1$discharge.date - df1$admit.date + 1
df2 <- df1[rep(row.names(df1), SEQ), 1:3]
df2$date <- df2$admit.date + sequence(SEQ)-1
df2[-3]
#     person admit       date
# 1        1     1 2010-01-01
# 1.1      1     1 2010-01-02
# 2        2     1 2010-01-01
# 2.1      2     1 2010-01-02
# 2.2      2     1 2010-01-03
# 3        3     1 2010-01-01
# 3.1      3     1 2010-01-02
# 3.2      3     1 2010-01-03
# 4        3     2 2010-02-01
# 4.1      3     2 2010-02-02
# 4.2      3     2 2010-02-03
```

Comment: I like what you do there with very few lines, but I need the actual dates as a variable as well (e.g., the df2["date"]).

Comment: FANTASTIC, and what I love the best about it, it uses no special packages/functions--all in base!

Comment: @Chris, for my benefit, which was the answer you were after :)

Comment: The last one, where you used df2$admit.date + sequence(SEQ)-1 to produce a vector of date sequences.  That was a pure data ninja move! +1